# Clearing a read() buffer while using a socket

Tags: c++, sockets, buffer

Recently I've been messing around with some sockets by trying to make a client/server program. So far I have been successful, but it seems I hit a roadblock. For some quick background information, I made a server that can accept a connection, and once everything is set up and a connection to a client is made, this block of code begins to exectue:

```
while(1){
        read(newsockfd, &inbuffer, 256);


        std::cout << "Message from client " << inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr) << " : ";
        for(int i = 0; i < sizeof(inbuffer); i++){
            std::cout << inbuffer[i];

        }
        std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Now the client simply, when executed, connects to the server and writes to the socket, and then exits. So since one message was sent, this loop should only run once, and then wait for another message if what I read was correct.

But what ends up happenning is that this loop continues over and over, printing the same message over and over. From what I read (on this site and others) about the read() function is that after it is called once, it waits for another message to be recieved. I may be making a stupid mistake here, but is there any way I can have this read() function wait for a new message, instead of using the same old message over and over? Or is there another function that could replace read() to do what I want it to?

Thanks for any help.

Comment: Do not add tags for unrelated languages. C is not C++ is not C

Comment: I put C because some of the libraries used are mean for C

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't check the return value of `read`. So if the other end closes the connection or there's an error, you'll just loop forever outputting whatever happened to be in the buffer. You probably want:

```
while(1){
    int msglen = read(newsockfd, &inbuffer, 256);
    if (msglen <= 0) break;

    std::cout << "Data from client " << inet_ntoa(cli_addr.sin_addr) << " : ";
    for(int i = 0; i < msglen; i++){
        std::cout << inbuffer[i];
    }
    std::cout << std::endl;

}
```

Notice that I changed the word "message" to "data". Here's why:

> So since one message was sent, this loop should only run once, and then wait for another message if what I read was correct.

This is incorrect. The code above does not have any concept of a "message", and TCP does not preserve application message boundaries. So not only is this wrong, there's no way it could be correct because the word "message" has no meaning that could possibly apply in this context. TCP does not "glue together" the bytes that happend to be passed in a single call to a sending function.